# How to make itunes stop asking "do you want to allow this computer to access information" on my iphone?

Tags: iphone, itunes, mojave

I have an iphone and a macbook. Whenever I plug the phone into the laptop for charging, itunes starts dancing in the dock cause this alert demands my attention:

> do you want to allow this computer to access information on
>
> if you don't allow access you will not be able to manage or sync your iphone with this computer

I always say no. This is a work laptop. I just want to charge my phone. I don't want to accidentally opt my phone into some draconian corporate device management. Is there a way to get itunes to never ever ask this again?

Comment: You could say yes and turn off auto sync in settings.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked this box in the laptop's iTunes preferences?

[image: iTunes device preferences]

Comment: Yes. This button is awesome for maintaining separate libraries between a mac and a phone. I can't tell that it does anything about this alert though.